# Count records per day using Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

This should be a simple one. I have tables in Access that contain data in 5 minute intervals for multiple years. All I want to do is count how many records per day I have, so I can determine if I'm missing any data for any day. I should have 288 per day. My horrible SQL code below only counts for each 5 minute interval... any help greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT Huth12_import.DateTime, Count(Huth12_import.DateTime) AS CountOfDateTime
FROM Huth12_import
GROUP BY Huth12_import.DateTime
ORDER BY Huth12_import.DateTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:**

Since your `DateTime` column contains date and time information stored as text, you could try to use **DateValue** function in Access (help on the function **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**), so the query could look even simpler:

```
SELECT 
    DateValue(Huth12_import.DateTime) AS DayVal, 
    Count(Huth12_import.DateTime) AS CountOfDateTime
FROM 
    Huth12_import
GROUP BY 
    DateValue(Huth12_import.DateTime)
ORDER BY 
    DayVal;
```

(DateVal functions should only return the date part of the stored information).

Comment: Ah, it gets better ... your solution looks like it'l lwork, except my dates are stored as short text in the format "10-OCT-2012 21:44:36.297". So I'm going to have to convert to date first. Either convert the actual column, or make a new column and run cDate().

Comment: Thx for your response. Please find my updated answer if you still need any assistance.

Comment: No problem - I'm glad it occured helpful :)

Comment: @monkey5672 If this solved your question, can you please mark this as the answer?